# Coloring a heatmap according to association type in R

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, heatmap, bioinformatics

Would it be possible to create a heatmap that will visualize the co-occurrence type among Gene Clusters pairs (X1 and X2 values from data frame).

I have already created a first analysis using networks. I want to possibly have this heatmap with their respective association types. From my dataframe I just want to make a heatmap that will be coloured according to the association type patterns.

1. I already created a first heatmap from absence-presence data:

## dataframe 1 (Exercpt)

```
GCF.No  |    Genome
GCF1135    Streptomyces_sp_MBT23
GCF1135    Streptomyces_sp_MBT4
GCF128     Streptomyces_sp_MBT86
GCF1328    Streptomyces_sp_Hm100
GCF1329    Streptomyces_sp_Hm100
GCF1330    Streptomyces_sp_Hm100
GCF1331    Streptomyces_sp_Hm100
GCF1331    Streptomyces_sp_Hm106
GCF1332    Streptomyces_sp_Hm100
GCF1334    Streptomyces_sp_Hm100
GCF1338    Streptomyces_sp_Hm100
GCF1338    Streptomyces_sp_Hm106
```

(I already created this into a binary table)

## code snippet

```
    image(df) # non-clustered heatmap
    my_palette <- colorRampPalette(c("gray", "black"))(n = 299)
    plot <- gplots::heatmap.2(df, margins=c(14,15),cexRow=0.57, cexCol=0.73,  main = 
    "GCF Content per Genome", trace="none", Rowv=TRUE, Colv=TRUE, col=my_palette)
```

[image: First Heatmap]

2. I would like to color according to association type **but am not sure how to do this:**

## Datatable Example

```
X1     | X2    | P(Prob) | Plt  | Pgt   | Association_Type 
GCF2423 GCF1393   0        0.99   0.0007   Positive
GCF2423 GCF1520   0        0.99   0.015    Positive
GCF2423 GCF3487   1        1      0.1      Random
GCF1393 GCF2423   0        1      0.02     Positive
GCF1393 GCF1520   1        0.03   0.99     Negative
GCF1520 GCF1393   0        0.045  0.93     Negative
GCF1520 GCF3517   1        1      0.04     Positive
GCF3487 GCF1520   0        1      0.99     Random
```

Where

pgt < 0.05 = "positive"
plt < 0.05 = "negative"

and random if it does not fall in above categories.

I would like something possibly like this or something similar?

[image]
<sub>(source: [techpowerup.org](https://img.techpowerup.org/200414/capture.png))</sub>

Comment: maybe something like this? https://griffithdan.github.io/pages/code_and_data/cooccur.html

Comment: @StupidWolf I actually have been using his package to determine association types between my gene clusters but the heatmap being created in his package is not very ideal, for which I wanted to try and make my own separate heatmap.